# Discord.py ctx.guild.edit works but not self.bot.guild.edit?

Tags: python, python-3.7, discord.py

Like the title says,
I'm trying to do guild edits but on an events.
Here's part of my code:

```
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def on_ready(self):
    server = self.bot.get_guild("serverid")
        while True:
            await self.bot.guild.edit(guild=server, name="foo")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await self.bot.guild.edit(guild=server, name="bar")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

I've already tested it with a standalone command, so I know that ctx.guild.edit works but I'm not sure how to get it to work in an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [`edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.edit) directly from the `Guild` object `server`

```
async def on_ready(self):
server = self.bot.get_guild(SERVER_ID)
while server is not None:
    await server.edit(name="foo")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await server.edit(name="bar")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Also, make sure that you're passing the id of the guild as an int and not a string, and the `guild_only` decorator should only be used on commands.